# how to update mysql with textfield and jcombobox in java

Tags: java, mysql

```
 private void UpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    //Update

    try{
        if(!(jTextField1.getText().isEmpty())){

        Connection myConn= null;
        Statement myStmt= null;
        ResultSet myRs= null;

        String user= "root";
        String pass= "passwd14";
       //Get Connection to database
        myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/company",user, pass);
        //Create a Statement
        myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
        //Prepared Statement
        PreparedStatement pst=null;

        try{

        String on= jTextField1.getText();

       //Prepare statement Execution
       String sql2 = "UPDATE amazon SET name =?, mob =?, oddt =? FROM amazon WHERE odn ='"+on+"'";
       pst=myConn.prepareStatement(sql2);
       //pst.setString(4,jTextField1.getText());
       pst.setString(1,jTextField2.getText());
       pst.setString(2,jTextField6.getText());
       pst.setString(3,jTextField5.getText());

       pst.executeUpdate();
       //Update ComboBox
       String s= (String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
       jComboBox1.setSelectedItem(s);
       String s2= (String)jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();
       jComboBox1.setSelectedItem(s2);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Record Saved..");

        }catch (Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Error");
        }

        }

        }catch (Exception ex){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this," This Error.. Keeps Showing up");
            }
 }
```

---

This is the database I want to update :

```
  amazon(name, mob, iss, stat, oddt, odn)
  that is (name, mobile, issue, status, order_details, orderno)
```

Comment: Is there an actual question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Query
It will work

```
String sql2 = "UPDATE amazon SET name =?, mob =?, oddt =? WHERE odn ='"+on+"'";
```

Comment: That Worked. Thank you very much !

Comment: @PranayKapgate Ok